# Three point correlation function 2D Ising model

Tags: correlation-functions, ising-model, critical-phenomena

What is the expected behaviour of the three point function $<\sigma_i \sigma_j  \sigma_k>$ of the Ising 2D model at the critical point where conformal symmetry is valid? Do they have a power-law behaviour with known critical exponents or they just vanish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is a unique Gibbs state at $\beta_{\rm c}$, these correlation functions (actually all odd correlation functions) vanish by symmetry : $\langle \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k \rangle_{\beta_{\rm c}} = \langle (-\sigma_i) (-\sigma_j) (-\sigma_k) \rangle_{\beta_{\rm c}} = -\langle \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k \rangle_{\beta_{\rm c}} \implies \langle \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_k \rangle_{\beta_{\rm c}} = 0$.